# Test Automation Framework - Stuck

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, automated-tests, citrix, testcomplete

I am wondering about where to start in building a test framework here.

1. I create a vb.net application to display the list of projects available. Allow user to select the project, time and date when test needs to get executed.
2. Once the user decides the time and task, I want my system to schedule a task onto a remote machine where the test execution would happen at the specified time.

I am stuck at point two. any pointers or question is much appreciated. 
I use testcomplete for automation.

Answer (score 2):

> I want my system to schedule a task onto a remote machine where the test execution would happen at the specified time

There's a [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and associated API that supports scheduling tasks at specific times. The API is aimed at C++ programmers.

You could use the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) available on CodePlex for easy interop with VB.Net.

The task to execute could be copied to a network drive so that it is accessible from the remote machine.

Comment: That definitely helped! 
I would want this task to be scheduled for some "X" user in my domain. Is that possible? 
Is it necessary that the "X" user should be available/logged in when I schedule a task? Am confused at that part!

Answer (score 1):

For point 2 you'll have to call TestComplete from the command line as per these instructions:

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55587/

You can also call TestExecute from the command line, it's a cut down version of Test Complete that will run your tests. Your license may or may not include that.

Did you also consider taking a look at Jenkins for scheduling your test runs?